Cannot connect between Wireguard peers
Using Wireguard om my Raspberry Pi 4 acts as a VPN server at home. I have forwarded port 51820 to the public IP address, so it is available on the public internet.
When I connect my Macbook to the VPN (peer 1) it works normally and has the same IP as my home IP as I am home.
Then I connect my cellphone with the VPN server as 'peer 2' using the 'official' Wireguard app which also works, regardless when connected to home wifi or mobile internet. In the latter case, the public IP of it is the same as my home IP even when wifi is off using mobile internet. That is how it should work.
But the issue is that I cannot connect between the Macbook over the wireguard virtual network between both devices.
I can ping my Macbook (10.12.0.1) from the phone (10.12.0.2) and the other way around.
But making SSH connection to the Mac fails (ssh user@10.8.0.1 from the phone), while nmap -v -Pn -p 22 10.8.0.1 issued from the phone returns that 22 is open. The same applies to port 80 : reported as open, but cannot open any website hosted on my Macbook. The other way around the same, it sees open ports but cannot connect to these ports.
Is this a fundamental Wireguard issue ?
Using OpenVPN (which I have also installed on all devices with a server on the Pi, I can interconnect between OpenVPN peers without problems, using the virtual 10.x.y.z ip addresses given by OpenVPN.
Server config (Raspberry Pi 4)
[Interface]
Address = 10.12.0.254/24
#SaveConfig = true
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = PRI

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUB1
AllowedIPs = 10.12.0.1/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUB2
AllowedIPs = 10.12.0.2/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUB3
AllowedIPs = 10.12.0.3/32


Peer 1 (Macbook)
[Interface]
Address = 10.12.0.1/24
DNS = 10.12.0.254
PrivateKey = PRIVATE1

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUB1
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = PUBLICIP:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Peer 2 (cellphone)
[Interface]
Address = 10.12.0.2/24
DNS = 10.12.0.254
PrivateKey = PRIVATE

[Peer]
PublicKey = PUB2
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = PUBLICIP:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25


If your WireGuard network is 10.12.0.0/24, then where does 10.8.0.1 come from?

The 10.8.0.1 is of the OpenVPN network where peer to peer does work. For WG, the 10.12.0.x subnet applies. Obviously I don't use both simultaneously.

You probably need a rule to allow in on wg0 out on wg0.
Some VPN software handles client-to-client forwarding internally, but WireGuard deliberately passes such packets down to the kernel's regular routing/forwarding so that they would be subject to firewall rules.

That indeed seems to work.
On the Raspberry Pi (the wireguard server) I set
sudo ufw route allow in on wg0 out on wg0 to 10.12.0.0/24
and then I was able to SSH into my cellphone from the Mac and the other way around, using the Wireguard app as VPN client.
